# dragenter, dragover and drop events not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, drag-and-drop, html5-canvas

I have the following code in my js file

```
window.onload = function () {

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas.addEventListener('dragover', drag_over, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('dragenter', drag_over, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('drop', dropped, false);
}
```

And at some point I create a draggable element like this

```
element.addEventListener('dragstart', dragstart, false);
```

I have callbacks like this:

```
function dragstart(e) {
    console.log("dragstart");
}

function dropped(e) {
    console.log("dropped");
 }
function drag_over(e) {
    console.log("dragover");
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

The problem is that the code works fine in chrome but not in firefox.
In firefox, dragstart callback gets fired but not the rest of them. Clueless :(

Comment: `dragenter` and `dragover` both use `drag_over`. Is that intended? Or is it a typo?

Answer (score 10):

It seems that you have to call `.setData()` in your `dragstart` function to actually make it work.

```
function dragstart(e) {
    console.log("dragstart");
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'dummy');
}
```

The following is from the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_operations):

> In HTML, apart from the default behavior for images, links, and
>   selections, no other elements are draggable by default. All XUL
>   elements are also draggable. In order to make another HTML element
>   draggable, two things must be done:
>
> - Set the draggable attribute to true on the element that you wish to make draggable.
> - Add a listener for the dragstart event and set the drag data within this listener.

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox you have to cancel the event on drag `dragover`:

```
function dragstart(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();     /// add this too

    console.log("dragstart");
}

function drag_over(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();     /// add this too

    console.log("dragover");
    return false;
}
```

See if that works for you!